# How simulation of ternary operator in Python works

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know there're some other articles talk about how to simulate ternary operator in Python, but my question here **is not** how can I simulate it, but **why do these ways work**.

As we all know simulating a ternary operator (condition: if_true ? if_false) is done by

```
a if condition else b
```

However, there're at least two other ways to accomplish that, e.g.

```
(if_false, if_true)[test]
```

and

```
(expression) and (if_true) or (if_false)
```

Example would be

```
(4, 5)[4 > 5]
```

gives 4

```
4 > 5 and 4 or 5
```

gives 5

Comment: There is extensive explanation of various ternary operator alternatives in [Does Python have a ternary conditional operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator)

Comment: @khelwood That question is not duplicate as I'm asking why do two other ways work, whereas the link you posted only tells what are the ways.

Answer (score 4):

That's because `boolean` in python is a subclass of `int`. And `True` is `1` while `False` is `0`. And that is being used as an index into the tuple. 
So,

```
(4, 5)[4 > 5]
>>> (4, 5)[False]
>>> (4, 5)[0]
>>> 4
```

Your second method is a bit more hard-to-read:

```
4 > 5 and 4 or 5
>>> ((4 > 5) and 4) or 5
>>> (False and 4) or 5
>>> False or 5
>>> 5
```

This one relies on the fact that `and` and `or` on truth-y or false-y values, yield the value and not a boolean.

Comment: There's some subtlety that might be initially confusing to some (it was for me). The result of the comparison is being used as an accessor. `4 > 5` evaluates to False, which as you've pointed out equals 0 and then we access the 0th element of the tuple `(4, 5)`